# Introduction to Occam 2

Tags: occam-pi

I'm looking for an online introduction to occam 2. Could some one help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Fred's tutorial](http://frmb.org/occtutor.html) and the [Concurrency.cc docs](http://concurrency.cc/docs/).

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search revealed [Programming in occam 2](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/people/geraint.jones/publications/book/Pio2/).